# NullRefernceException when adding XElement to a XDocument

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, xelement

I have the following .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Params>
  <Name>Resolver1</Name>
  <RemoteHosts>
    <Host>
      <Name>Locale</Name>
       <IP>localhost</IP>
       <Port>8082</Port>
     </Host>
  </RemoteHosts>
</Params>
```

Now, when I try to add another "Host" in the "RemoteHosts" section using the following code it raises a NullReferenceException:

```
XDocument xmlList = XDocument.Load("NetConfig.xml");

xmlList.Element("RemoteHosts").Add(new XElement("Host",    
new XElement("Name", h.name),
new XElement("IP", h.IP),
new XElement("Port", h.port)));
```

anyway the

```
xmlList.Save("NetConfig.xml");
```

works well, saving the new item...what's wrong?

Comment: can you debug to find out what is actually null? Is it the h variable, or maybe the "RemoteHosts" node? Not clear.

Comment: Does your saved file contain that new `Host` node?

Comment: @ek_ny the xmlList.Element("RemoteHosts") is null..

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't make sense object from which you're calling `Add` is null and the node you're adding is actually added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XmlList contains only 1 node and its `Params` not `RemoteHosts`

Comment: Thank you! Now using      xmlList.Element("Params").Element("RemoteHosts").Add ... it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try `xmlList.Root.Element("RemoteHosts")`